# Incorrect syntax; EE.EnemyId could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

```
SELECT YEAR(EpisodeDate), EN.EnemyName, Count (*) AS [Number of Episodes]
FROM tblEpisode AS E INNER JOIN
     tblEpisodeEnemy AS EE
     ON EE.EpisodeId = E.EpisodeId INNER JOIN
     tblEnemy AS EN INNER JOIN
     ON EE.EnemyId = EN.EnemyId
GROUP BY EpisodeDate, EnemyName
```

Comment: The column doesn't exist in the table.  Fix the name.

Comment: For some reason it did work after switching the appearance order of the joins in the sentence, that column does exist

Answer (score 1):

This will not fix your syntax error (which is because you are referencing a column that doesn't exist in the table).

But, no doubt, you want one row per year.  So, you need to fix your `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT YEAR(EpisodeDate), EN.EnemyName, Count(*) AS num_episodes
FROM tblEpisode E INNER JOIN
     tblEpisodeEnemy EE
     ON EE.EpisodeId = E.EpisodeId INNER JOIN
     tblEnemy EN INNER JOIN
     ON EE.EnemyId = EN.EnemyId
GROUP BY YEAR(EpisodeDate), EN.EnemyName
```

Answer (score 0):

you got syntax error due to the extra INNER JOIN

```
SELECT YEAR(EpisodeDate), EN.EnemyName, Count (*) AS [Number of Episodes]
FROM tblEpisode AS E INNER JOIN
     tblEpisodeEnemy AS EE
     ON EE.EpisodeId = E.EpisodeId INNER JOIN
     tblEnemy AS EN /*INNER JOIN*/
     ON EE.EnemyId = EN.EnemyId
GROUP BY EpisodeDate, EnemyName
```